# Filter Column based on a value inside the cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a VBA noob. I need help working out this filter:
My data has ~50,000 rows and 100 columns. The column I want to filter has values like TL-98.263138472% BD-1.736861528%. I want to filter out all the values in VBA where TL>90%. I can think of a long way of doing it - where I create a loop, break down each cell, then look at TL, then the 4 numbers next to it. But it sounds like it would take forever. Wondering if there's a faster/easier way to do it? Also wondering, if it's even worth it. If it would take even more than 2 seconds, then I would rather not do it with VBA.
I have not coded it yet, wanted to see if anyone has better ideas than what I came up with.
Thanks in advance! Adding an example of my data below:
[image]

Comment: You seems to have a good idea of how to do it, so why not code it and test the speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty fast in my tests:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, t
    Dim i As Long, rng As Range, rngFilt As Range, arr, arrFilt
    
'    For i = 2 To 50000 'create some dummy data
'        Cells(i, "A") = "TL-" & 50 + (Rnd() * 60) & "% BD-1.736861528%"
'    Next i
'    [B2:CV50000].value="blah"  'fill rest of table
    
    t = Timer
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) 'range of values to filter
    Set rngFilt = rng.Offset(0, 110) 'a range off to the right to filter on
    
    arr = rng.Value
    arrFilt = rngFilt.Value  'for holding filtering flags
    arrFilt(1, 1) = "Filter" 'column header
    
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
        arrFilt(i, 1) = IIf(FilterOut(arr(i, 1)), "Y", "N")
    Next i
    
    rngFilt.Value = arrFilt
    rngFilt.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="N"
    
    Debug.Print Timer - t
    
End Sub


'does this value need to be filtered out?
Function FilterOut(v) As Boolean
    Dim pos As Long
    pos = InStr(v, "TL-")
    If pos > 0 Then
        v = Mid(v, pos + 3)
        pos = InStr(v, "%")
        If pos > 0 Then
            v = Left(v, pos - 1)
            'Debug.Print v
            If IsNumeric(v) Then FilterOut = v > 90
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

This ran in <0.3 sec for me, on a 50k row X 100 col dataset

Answer (score 1):

## Filter Via Table Helper Column and String Parse

It you want to look into non VBA solutions, You could use a helper column to decide it it's worth filtering out.

First we need to find "TL-" in the string, then find "%" After that:

> `MID(A4,FIND("TL-",A4)+3,FIND("%",A4,FIND("TL-",A4)+3)-FIND("TL-",A4)-3)`

This will just return us that value sub string, regardless or position.
Now we need to convert it into a value... and I'm told that --( ) isn't the correct way to convert a string to a value... but i keep using it and it keeps working.

Anyway, finally we test if that is larger than 90 like:

> `=IF(--(MID(A4,FIND("TL-",A4)+3,FIND("%",A4,FIND("TL-",A4)+3)-FIND("TL-",A4)-3))>90,"Remove","Keep")`

---

### Here's my example:

[image]

### And the final result.

[image]

### And Filtered:

[image]

Comment: Oh, i just remembered, I think you can use `Value()` to convert a string to numeric value

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Values (Efficiently!?)

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()

Dim T As Double: T = Timer
    
    ' Read Data: Write the values from the source range to an array.

    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_COLUMN As Long = 44
    Const CRIT_STRING_LEFT As String = "TL-"
    Const CRIT_VALUE_GT As Double = 90
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Sheet2"

    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Write to the array (practically this line uses up all the time).
    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value ' assumes at least two cells in 'srg'
    
Debug.Print "Read Data:   " & Format(Timer - T, "0.000s")
T = Timer
    
    ' Modify Data: Write the critical values to the top of the array.
    
    Dim cLen As Long: cLen = Len(CRIT_STRING_LEFT)
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 1 ' skip headers
    
    Dim sr As Long, c As Long
    Dim cPos As Long, cNum As Double, cString As String
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount ' skip headers
        cString = CStr(Data(sr, SRC_COLUMN))
        cPos = InStr(1, cString, CRIT_STRING_LEFT, vbTextCompare)
        If cPos > 0 Then
            cString = Right(cString, Len(cString) - cPos - cLen + 1)
            cString = Replace(cString, "%", "")
            cNum = Val(cString) ' 'Val' doesn't work with "!,@,#,$,%,&,^"
            If cNum > CRIT_VALUE_GT Then ' 'Evaluate' is too slow!
                dr = dr + 1
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
                Next c
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
Debug.Print "Modify Data: " & Format(Timer - T, "0.000s")
T = Timer
    
    ' Write Data: Write the values from the array to the destination range.
    
    If dr = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no filtered values
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").Resize(dr, cCount)
    
    ' Write to the range (practically this line uses up all the time).
    drg.Value = Data
    ' Clear below
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
    
Debug.Print "Write Data:  " & Format(Timer - T, "0.000s")
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

**The Result (Time Passed)**

- On a sample of `50k` rows by `100` columns of data with `26k` matches, the code finished in under `5s`:

  ```
  Read Data:   1.336s
  Modify Data: 0.277s
  Write Data:  3.375s
  ```
- There were no blank cells and each cell in the criteria column contained the criteria string with a percentage hence it should be faster on your data. Your feedback is expected.